# MYSQL update table query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

MYSQL update query

I need to update values form one table to another and create values if they are not there
How can I do this for all values or form values from one ID to another

This is the query but I need to run it for every ID and that is a lot of job, so is there any simplier way?

So id_product is always the same

`

```
INSERT INTO ps_product_supplier 
(id_product_supplier, id_product, id_product_attribute, id_supplier,
product_supplier_reference, product_supplier_price_te, id_currency)  
VALUES(NULL, 6216, 0, (SELECT id_supplier FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = 6216,
(SELECT supplier_reference FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = 6216), 
(SELECT wholesale_price FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = 6216), 3);
```

Comment: you should go to documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_product_supplier 
(id_product_supplier, id_product, id_product_attribute, id_supplier,
product_supplier_reference, product_supplier_price_te, id_currency)  
SELECT NULL, id_product, 0, id_supplier, supplier_reference, wholesale_price, 3
FROM ps_product
```

The keyword `IGNORE` will allow the query to insert only the records that are not already in the destination table. It will work only if your destination table has a primary key (or unique key) on the field `id_product_supplier`.

Comment: Will I overwrite id_products with this?

Comment: I have tried it, but problem is that some fields do not exists so it did not do anything

Comment: 0 rows inserted. ( Query took 0.1925 sec )

It does nothing

Comment: This is not an error message. The query works, but there was no data to insert: either the table `ps_product` is empty, or the table `ps_product_supplier` already contains the records you are trying to insert.

Comment: The problem is with this query that it wont crate new because uniq key is id_product and it cannot overwrite it. When IGORE is not used the i get PK error, so It has to be something like my query